# setOnUtteranceProgressListener for API < 15

Tags: android, callback, listener, text-to-speech

I'm making an application for Android API 11 (or newer). I'm trying to get callbacks from a TTS engine, but there a problem appears. I've tried to set a listener using `setOnUtteranceProgressListener()` method but Eclipse says that requires API 15 or newer (and throws a compilation error), so next I've tried to use `setOnUtteranceCompletedListener()` but than it says "This method was deprecated in API level 15". What should I use to make it compatible with API 11 and higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use the deprecated methods or do one of the depending on which Android version the device is running. You can look at Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        // API > 15
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                // do something
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                 // do something
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                 // do something
            }
        });
    } else {
        // API < 15
        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                  // do something
            }
        });
    }
```